# SqlConnection.Open() returns a StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I tried to find a solution for this but couldn't. Here's the problem:

I'm loading data of a bunch of users and creating an object for each user. Each user object has many object properties. Here's the structure:

```
public class User {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public City City { get; set; }
   public Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

The City class:

```
public class City {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

The Office class:

```
public class Office {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }
}
```

The user object has many other similar properties like City & Office which are basically class objects.

Now here's the main issue. Whenever I try to load all the users into a collection of dictionary, StackOverflow exception occurs at SqlCon.Open() (See the "Fetch" function I've written below). Here's how I'm loading everything:

```
//Code to load users
Dictionary<int, User> Users = new Dictionary<int, Users>();
DataTable usersData = new DataTable();

//The Fetch function has two version. The first one; which is mentioned in this post, returns the result as Dictionary<string, object>(). 
//The second version of the function returns the result in the form of the a DataTable and is only used when multiple rows are required from the database. The following returns a set of rows in a DataTable.

Globals.MainDatabase.Fetch("SELECT * FROM users", out usersData);

foreach (DataRow row in usersData.Rows) {
    User user = new User();
    user.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
    user.Name = row["name"].ToString();
    user.City = Cities.Get(Convert.ToInt32(row["city_id"]));
    user.Office = Offices.Get(Convert.ToInt32(row["office_id"]));
    Users.Add(user.ID, user);
}
```

The methods "Cities.Get(Int32 id)" and "Offices.Get(Int32 id)" uses the following function to fetch data from the database.

```
public void Fetch(string query, out Dictionary<string, object> results) {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        try {
            using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
                using (SqlCmd = new SqlCommand()) {
                    SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
                    SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlCmd.CommandText = query;

                    SqlCon.Open();

                    DataTable temp = new DataTable();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter SqlAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)) {
                        SqlAdp.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
                        SqlAdp.Fill(temp);
                    }

                    DataRow row = temp.Rows[0];
                    temp = null;
                    dict = row.Table.Columns
                           .Cast<DataColumn>()
                           .ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => row.Field<object>(col.ColumnName));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            HandleException(ex, "An error occurred when tried to fetch data.", query);
        }

        results = dict;
        dict = null;
    }
```

I realize that this "Fetch" function is being called multiple times when creating the user object. The "StackOverflow" exception occurs exactly at this line:

```
SqlCon.Open();
```

How can I solve this error? or probably I should use a better approach to do this?

Comment: Is HandleException calling itself by any chance? Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Well, for sure setting the _temp_ variable to null before using the _row_ and referencing the Table doesn't seem to be a great idea. At least move the temp=null after setting the _dict_

Comment: @Steve: Setting the `temp` variable to `null` before or after setting `dict` makes no difference at all. The reference to the data table is not used any more in the code after getting the data row. Setting the reference to null at all is pointless.

Comment: Yes, just seems to be so wrong..

Comment: So what's on the stack?

Comment: Usually a stack overflow is caused by infinite recursion. I don't find any recursive code in what you have shown, so the problem is likely in the code outside that. The code where the stack overflow is thrown is just the point in the code where the stack finally grew too much, the actual problem is the code that makes the stack grow in the first place.

Comment: @Guffa Man you saved me today, cheers. Check out my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright folks, I figured it out. It was all because of faulty architecture of the whole demo application. Some objects have one or more other objects as properties and due to some silly faults in the architecture; the "fetch" operation which serves as the base of fetching data from the database, was recursively called resulting into StackOverflow exception which was actually a large number of database connections being initialized ultimately growing the heap size to an extent which causes the exception.

I tried to summarize everything in the paragraph written above because posting the complete source code is useless considering the large amount of code.

Thank you everyone who helped, especially @Guffa's comment on the main post which forced me to investigate the whole issue from scratch rather than sticking to the exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

A bit too long for a comment

- Do you really need to load `ALL` data from the database? It is better to just grab the columns and rows you need.
- Why are you copying `DataTables` in to `Dictionaries`? What is wrong with just using a `DataTable`?
- *99.9%* of the time you will have better performance performing `JOIN`s in the database.
- Don't try to roll your own 'ORM'. Use something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) if you don't want the bloat of EF or NHibernate. Or, stick to ADO (`DataTable`, `DataAdapter` etc.)

Comment: This sounds resonable. This also sounds unrelated to the stack overflow error, IMO.

Comment: 1. I've two account types. First one is 'user', which are regular employees and the second one is 'clients'. There would be no more than 50-75 'users' and the data displayed carries the details of the user who added / modified / updated it. That's why rather then accessing the database hundreds of time during few minutes, I'm loading the user details into local memory. 

2. Fetch function has different versions. This one is only used when a single row of data is required which is ultimately converted into a dictionary. I know DataTables can be used as well, but one table for a single row, nope

Comment: (3) Thank you, will look into this. (4) Thank you again, will check out that one as well. This code is just; you can say, a prototype. I'm trying out different things and will stick to the best one.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
```

Is your connection string variable really named ConnectionString? Is it possible you are having a name clash with the type? Since it is not declared in the shown code, I assume it is a class variable, so you should respect the conventional naming convention, which would be `_connectionString`. What does your connection string look like?

Comment: The "fetch" function actually is a part of a class and the connection string is initialized through the constructor. ConnectionString is a property of the database object.